# How to delete the oldest lines from log file using logback?

Tags: android, file, logging, filesize, max-size

I wrote code based on this solution: https://gist.github.com/umangmathur92/a65f67c01e2b425289b8

```
        LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        lc.reset();
        final String LOG_DIR = context.getExternalCacheDir() + File.separator + ".ts";
        RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<>();
        rollingFileAppender.setAppend(true);
        rollingFileAppender.setContext(lc);
        rollingFileAppender.setLazy(true);
        rollingFileAppender.setFile(LOG_DIR + File.separator + "ts.log");
        SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<ILoggingEvent> trigPolicy = new SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<>();
        trigPolicy.setMaxFileSize(new FileSize(1024 * 256));
        trigPolicy.setContext(lc);
        trigPolicy.start();
        FixedWindowRollingPolicy rollingPolicy = new FixedWindowRollingPolicy();
        rollingPolicy.setContext(lc);
        rollingPolicy.setParent(rollingFileAppender);
        rollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern(LOG_DIR + File.separator + "ts.%i.log");
        rollingPolicy.setMinIndex(1);
        rollingPolicy.setMaxIndex(1);
        rollingPolicy.start();
        rollingFileAppender.setTriggeringPolicy(trigPolicy);
        rollingFileAppender.setRollingPolicy(rollingPolicy);
        PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
        encoder.setPattern("%msg%n");
        encoder.setContext(lc);
        encoder.start();
        rollingFileAppender.setEncoder(encoder);
        rollingFileAppender.start();
        ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger root = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        root.addAppender(rollingFileAppender);
```

But this is not what I wanted to do. This code deletes all the file when reaches specefied limit and begins to write a new one (so, after reaching 256KB limit file then takes 10KB *for example*).

I want to limit file size to 256KB and I want to clear the oldest lines to release space for new ones.

Example:

```
Line 1 sample text.
Line 2 sample text.
Line 3 sample text.
Line 4 sample text.
Line 5 sample text.
```

Imagine, that these lines takes 256KB, and when I write new line:

```
Line 6 sample text.
```

I want this file to look like:

```
Line 2 sample text.
Line 3 sample text.
Line 4 sample text.
Line 5 sample text.
Line 6 sample text.
```

Comment: @Henry thank you, I think that you can post this as answer, because it is the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require to rewrite the whole file whenever a line is deleted from the beginning. Therefore, this would be a performance bottleneck. The usual solution is to start a new log file when the old one has reached a certain size.